# Direct limit of a directed system

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to compute direct limit of a directed system.

I understand the definition but I did not really compute what is a direct limit of a directed system given one such directed system.

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $I$ be a directed set.  A
>   collection of objects $\{F_i\}$ indexed by elements of $I$ along with
>   morphims $f_{ij}:F_i\rightarrow F_j$ indexed by elements $(i,j)$ with
>   $i\leq j$ is said to be a directed system if
>
> - $f_{ii}$ is identity on $F_i$.
> - For $i\leq j\leq k$ we have $f_{ik}=f_{jk}\circ f_{ij}$ in $F_i\xrightarrow{f_{ij}}F_j\xrightarrow{f_{jk}} F_k$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $(F_i,f_{ij})$ be a directed system in  $\mathcal{C}$. 
>   An object $G$ in $\mathcal{C}$ along with morphisms $\phi_i:F_i\rightarrow G$ for each $i\in I$ is called a direct limit 
>   if $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ f_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ with $i\leq j$ and, given any object $H$ along with morphisms $\psi:F_i\rightarrow H$ for each
>   $i\in I$ with $\psi_i=\psi_j\circ f_{ij}$, there exists a unique morphism $\Phi:G\rightarrow H$ such that $\psi_i=\Phi\circ \phi_i$ for all 
>   $i\in I$.

Let $A_1\xrightarrow{f_{12}}A_2\xrightarrow{f_{23}}A_3\rightarrow \cdots$ be a directed system indexed by natural numbers. Other maps $A_m\rightarrow A_n$ for $m\leq n$ is just the composition $A_m\rightarrow A_{m+1}\rightarrow \cdots\rightarrow A_n$.

Now, I need to construct a set $B$ with maps $A_i\rightarrow B$ for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$ with some universal property.

I guess $B$ is the disjoint union of $A_i$. Say $B=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}{n}\times A_n$. We have maps $A_i\xrightarrow{\phi_i} B$ by $x_i\mapsto (n,x_i)$. We need to have $\phi_i(x_i)=\phi_j(f_{ij}(x_i))$ for all $i\leq j$.

We need to have $(i,x_i)=(j,f_{ij}x_i)$ for all $i\leq j$. As this is always not true in $B$, we consider the quotient of $B$ by these conditions i.e., $(i,x_i)=(j,f_{ij}(x_i))$ for all $i\leq j$ and call this quotient $C$. So, 
$$C=\left(\bigsqcup_{\{n\}\in \mathbb{N}}{n}\times A_n\right){\bigg /}\sim$$
where $(i,x_i)\sim (j,f_{ij}(x_i))$.

I claim this is the direct limit of $(A_i)$. I could not prove the universal property. Please give hints for that and comment whether $C$ is a right choice or not.

Comment: What category $\mathcal C$ are you working in? **Set**?

Comment: The definition is for any category. I am working in Set categroy. @HagenvonEitzen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $C$ is correct. Let $\pi\colon B\to C$ denote the quotient map.

Let $H$ be a set together with maps $\psi_i\colon A_i\to H$ such that $\psi_{i+1}\circ f_{i,i+1}=\psi_i$ for all $i$. 
Then we can define a map $\Phi\colon C\to H$ as follows:
Given $c\in C$, pick $b\in B$ with $\pi(b)=c$. Then $b=(n,a)$ for aome $n\in\Bbb N$ and $a\in A_n$. Set $\Phi(c):=\psi_n(a)$. This is well-defined: If also $\phi(b')=c$ for some $b'=(n',a')$ with $a'\in A_{n'}$, then $\psi_{n'}(a')=\psi_n(a)$ because (say, in the simplest case that $n'=n$) $a'=f_{n,n'}(a)$ and so $\psi_{n'}(a')=\psi_{n'}(f_{n,n'}(a))=\psi_n(a)$.
It is also clear that we *must* define $\Phi$ as described above, i.e., $\Phi$ is unique.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this $C$ works for more general categories as groups, rings, modules, topological spaces..

Answer (score 3):

In the category of sets, $B$ is not exactly the disjoint union of the $A_i$s (which is the coproduct in $\operatorname{Set}$).

It is the quotient of $\coprod_\limits{i\in\mathbf N} A_i$ by the equivalence relation:
$$x_i\sim x_j\iff\exists k\ge i,\,;f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_j).$$

Note that, in case the $A_i$s are subsets of a larger set and the morphisms are the inclusion morphisms, the direct limit is nothing else than the union of all $A_i$s.  From this point of view, we can say direct limits are a vast generalisation of set-theoretic union, in the context of category theory.

Comment: I guess I understand that equivalence relation to some extent. Suppose $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_j)$. The equivalence relation that I have mentioned says that $(i,x_i)=(k,f_{ik}(x_i))$ and $(j,x_j)=(k,f_{jk}(x_j))$. As $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_j)$ we need to have $(i,x_i)=(j,x_j)$ and in another notation, we need to have $x_i=x_j$. Other direction also follows similarly. Can you please tell me why did you choose to write this equivalence relation than the one that I have mentioned.

Comment: @cello: I hadn't seen it. I guess it happened with your edit, while I was typing my answer? There's one difference with my answer: it is valid even if the indexing set is not totally ordered as $\mathbf N$. In the general case, $f_{ij}(x_i)$ may very well not exist, but there must be a $k\ge i,j$ such that $f_{ik}$ and  $f_{jk}$ both exist (hence $f_{ik}(x_i)$ and  $f_{jk}(x_j)$ both exist).

Comment: I have only edited the way that I have written $C$ before. Content was same. You are saying $f_{ij}(x_i)$ may not exists at all but, I solved for the equivalence relation from the condition that $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ f_{ij}$ for $i\leq j$. So, $f_{ij}(x_i)$ exists.. what am I missing? :O

Comment: With your indexing set, nothing. But there are more general indexing sets (‘directed’ or ‘filtered’) sets.

Comment: I do not understand this. Please explain more. It is  the definition that forces to consider (i,j)
with $i≤j$ in $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ f_{ij}$. You are definitely making me eager to understand this better. Please suggest some refeence if you are busy

Comment: Yes: the index  must have a preorder, and be directed, as I said. A typical example is indexing by the subsets of a set (or the submodules of a module): these are not totally ordered sets, but they're directed, i.e. every pair of elements has an upper bound. You can take a look at Wikipedia : [Direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) and [Directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set).

Comment: I will try to be more specific this time. It is the definition that forces to consider the condition $i\leq j$ and asks us that we need to have $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ f_{ij}$, which is what gives me the condition $(i,x_i)=(j,f_{ij}(x_i))$. Then, where is the question of considering  the case 
where $f_{ij}(x_i)$ does not exists. I looked at wikipedia and it says the same thing that you are saying

Comment: Well, $f_{ij}(x_i)$ does not always exist simply because $f_{ij}$ does not exist. On Wikipedia, they're considering the general case, even for for countable set of indices. Such a countable set, in real life, is for instance $\mathbf N$, ordered by divisibility.

Comment: The condition $\phi_i=\phi_j\circ f_{ij}$ makes sense only when $f_{ij}$ exists and only from this condition I deduced that equivalence relation.  How are you deducing your equivalence condition if not from this condition which requires existence of $f_{ij}$

Comment: That's because the images are equal some step further ($\exists k\dots$).

Comment: It is clear now.. you could have asked me the following question.. Ok. Let $(i,x_i),(j,x_j)\in C=B/\sim$. How do you say they are equal?. Further, suppose that there is no relation $i\leq j$ or $j\leq i$. Then, I would have told you the following : ``Oh. Yes. We only have relation between $(i,x_i)$ and $(k,f_{ik}(x_i))$ and not some random $(i,x_i)$ and $(j,x_j)$. As $I$ is a directed set, there exists $k$ with $i\leq k$ and $j\leq k$. So, we have $(i,x_i)=(k,f_{ik}(x_i))$ and $(j,x_j)=(k,f_{jk}(x_k))$. So, for $(i,x_i)=(j,x_j)$ we need to have $(k,f_{ik}(x_i))=(k,f_{jk}(x_k))$ which is"

Comment: same as saying $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_j)$, which is what you have mentioned. Thus, these two definitions are same. In my first comment, I assumed that $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_j)$ and prove that $(i,x_i)=(j,x_j)$. I said other direction follows similarly but did not write down which is why I was not happy. Now, It is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct object $C$. Here's a proof of the universal property of the colimit (direct limit) using universal property of disjoint sums and quotient.

First notice that disjoint sum in $\textbf{Set}$ is the coproduct. And taking quotient by a relation has the following universal property : given an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $X$, we have a morphism  $\pi:X\to X/_\sim$ such that for any morphism $f:X\to Y$, satisfying $a\sim b\implies f(a)=f(b)$, there exists a unique morphism $\tilde{f}:X/_\sim\to Y$, with $f = \tilde{f}\circ\pi$.

Now, you have defined $B=\coprod F_i$ and $C=B/_\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation given by the directed system. To show that $C$ is the colimit, say you have a collection of morphism $\psi_i:F_i\to H$, which is compatible with the direct system. Firstly, from the coproduct, you get a unique morphism $\psi:B\to H$. Notice that $b\sim b'\implies\psi(b)=\psi(b')$. So again by the universal property of the quotient, you get a unique map $\Psi:C\to G$, as required. Thus, $C$ is the colimit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)