# Exactness of direct limits functor

Tags: category-theory

This is continuation of [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426428/direct-limit-of-a-directed-system) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426597/maps-between-direct-limits).

I am trying to prove that suppose we have $\varphi_i:A_i\rightarrow B_i$ is injective for each $i$. Then, $\Phi:\varinjlim A_i\rightarrow \varinjlim B_i$ is injective.

For simplicity, I work with category of sets. 
Suppose $(i,x_i), (j,x_j)\in \varinjlim A_i$ be such that $\Phi(i,x_i)=\Phi(j,x_j)$. We have $(i,x_i)=\tau_i(x_i)$ and $(j,x_j)=\tau_j(x_j)$. So, 
$$(\Phi\circ \tau_i)(x_i)=(\Phi\circ \tau_j)(x_j)$$
From the commutative diagram in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426597/maps-between-direct-limits) we have  $$\eta_i(\varphi_i(x_i))=\eta_j(\varphi_j(x_j))$$
i.e., $(i, \varphi_i(x_i))=(j,\varphi_j(x_j))$. So, $\varphi_j(x_j)=g_{ij}(\varphi_i(x_i))=\varphi_j(f_{ij}(x_i))$. As $\varphi_j$
 is injective, we have $x_j=f_{ij}(x_i)$ i.e., $(i,x_i)=(j,x_j)$. Thus, 
$\Phi:\varinjlim A_i\rightarrow \varinjlim B_i$ is injective.

Is my justification sufficient to conclude that $\Phi$ is injective?

Do we have any general idea to attack in case of general categories?

Comment: Regarding the title, the filtered colimits *aren't* exact in general. For example, filtered colimits in the abelian category $\mathbf{Ab}^{\mathrm{op}}$ are generally not exact. (because cofiltered limits in $\mathbf{Ab}$ aren't)

Comment: @Hurkyl I do not understand what you are saying. I do not know what are diltered colimits. cofiltered limits. Are you saying I have given some wrong justification here?

Comment: @cello No, Hurkyl's saying that this can't be proved in a general category.

Comment: @cello: "Direct limit" is an older term for "directed colimit", which is basically the same as but slightly more cumbersome version of "filtered colimit". Similarly for "Inverse limit" and "cofiltered limit".

Comment: @KevinCarlson Ok.

Comment: @Hurkyl Can you say  why this can not happen in  general category? Assuming limit exists I think it should follow though I can not see why

Comment: The category of sets is a very particular category; you can't expect that something that holds in it also holds in other categories. Besides “injective” usually refers to maps; in general category theory one usually refers to “monic” morphisms. And, no, direct limits of monics is not in general monic.

Comment: I was thinking at least in case where objects are sets with some extra structure, this proof should work @egreg ?? I do not really understand why it does not work in $\textbf{Ab}^{\text{op}}$. Objects are abelian groups and just morphisms get reversed. Why should it not work?

Comment: @cello The simplest way to see it is to realize that products are not exact in $\mathbf{Ab}$.

Comment: @egreg : I will check that products are not exact in that category. But, can you tell me what goes wrong with this proof in case of opposite category of abelian groups? They are also sets with extra structure. So, direct limit functor should be exact... :O Sorry.. Is it that in opposite category they are not sets? :O

Comment: Ok. @egreg i will spend some more time on what you said before asking you to explain further. Thank you :)

Comment: @egreg Infinite product are exact in the category of abelian groups. Did you mean inverse limits (indexed by a (co)directed category) ?

Comment: @Roland Yes, I was simplifying too much.

Comment: @cello You should not think of the opposite category of sets as a concrete category (I'm not claiming it isn't). But as egreg say, even in a concrete category, direct limit might not be exact. Now look at the following *inverse* systems : $0\rightarrow p^i\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$ with transition maps being the obvious ones. Take inverse limit : $0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_p$ where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are the p-adic integer. This is not right exact. Hence, in the opposite category, the direct limit is not exact.

Comment: @Roland thanks for your example. I need some more time to sink this into me. :D :D

Comment: Why downvote???